# Create two tables in word with php COM("word.application")

Tags: php, ms-word, com

I wrote a code that create a word document.
My intension was to create two separated tables, but I cannot do it: the first one is created inside the second one.
This is the code:

```
<?php   
$word= new COM("word.application") or die("Unable to create Word document"); 
// Hide MS Word application window
$word->Visible = 0;
//Create new document
$WrdDoc = $word->Documents->Add();
// Define page margins 
$word->Selection->PageSetup->LeftMargin = '2';
$word->Selection->PageSetup->RightMargin = '2';
// Define font settings
$word->Selection->Font->Name = 'Times New Roman';
$word->Selection->Font->Size = 18;
// Add text
$word->Selection->ParagraphFormat->Alignment = 1;
$word->Selection->TypeText("Questo e' il PDP!\n");

$materia[0] = "Italiano";
$materia[1] = "Storia";
$strumenti_compensativi[0] = "Mappe concettuali";
$strumenti_compensativi[1] = "Calcolatrice";
$misure_dispensative[0] = "Lettura ad alta voce";
$misure_dispensative[1] = "Scrittura sotto dettatura";

for( $i=0; $i<2; $i++ ) {
    $word->Selection->Font->Name = 'Times New Roman';
    $word->Selection->Font->Size = 16;
    $word->Selection->TypeText("$materia[$i]\n");

    $WTable = $WrdDoc->Tables->Add($word->Selection->Range, 2, 2); // Colums, Rows
    $WrdDoc->Tables[1]->Borders->InsideLineStyle=1; 
    $WrdDoc->Tables[1]->Borders->OutsideLineStyle = 1;

    $WTable->Cell(1,1)->Width = "3"; 
    $WTable->Cell(1,2)->Width = "12";   
    $WTable->Cell(1,1)->Range->Font->Name = "Times New Roman";
    $WTable->Cell(1,1)->Range->Shading->BackgroundPatternColor = hexdec ( "00ff00" );
    $WTable->Cell(1,1)->Range->Font->Size = 12;
    $WTable->Cell(1,1)->Range->Bold = False;
    $WTable->Cell(1,1)->Range->Font->Italic = False;
    $WTable->Cell(1,1)->Range->Text = "Strumenti compensativi";
    $WTable->Cell(1,2)->Range->Font->Size = 12;
    $WTable->Cell(1,2)->Range->Bold = False;
    $WTable->Cell(1,2)->Range->Font->Italic = False;
    $WTable->Cell(1,2)->Range->Text = "$strumenti_compensativi[$i]"; 

    $WTable->Cell(2,1)->Width = "3"; 
    $WTable->Cell(2,2)->Width = "12";   
    $WTable->Cell(2,1)->Range->Font->Name = "Times New Roman";
    $WTable->Cell(2,1)->Range->Shading->BackgroundPatternColor = hexdec ( "00ff00" );
    $WTable->Cell(1,1)->Range->Font->Size = 12;
    $WTable->Cell(1,1)->Range->Bold = False;
    $WTable->Cell(1,1)->Range->Font->Italic = False;
    $WTable->Cell(2,1)->Range->Text = "Misure dispensative";
    $WTable->Cell(2,2)->Range->Font->Size = 12;
    $WTable->Cell(2,2)->Range->Bold = False;
    $WTable->Cell(2,2)->Range->Font->Italic = False;
    $WTable->Cell(2,2)->Range->Text = "$misure_dispensative[$i]";       

}

// Save document
$filename = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "word");
$word->Documents[1]->SaveAs($filename);

$file="ilMiofile.doc";

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-word');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="ilMiofile.doc"');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($filename);
unlink($filename);

// Close and quit
$word->quit();
unset($word);

echo "done"; 
?>
```

Can someone help me please...? I think the problem is that I don't close the first table before start the second one. If yes, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't use php, but it appears the language uses Word's object model, with which I *am* familiar... Since you haven't received a reply, yet, I'll attempt to describe a method, but the code I show is a theoretical extension based on what you post - I'm not able to test it.

It would help if you would work with the `Range` object. Assign the table's `Range` to a Range object. Insert a paragraph at the end of the Range (every Word table must be followed by a paragraph). Then collapse the Range to its end-point, providing the "target" for inserting the second table.

That would be something like this, if I'm correctly interpreting the php syntax:

```
$tableRange = $WTable->Range;
$tableRange->InsertAfter(ANSI-13); //Substitute php code for ANSI 13 character
$tableRange->Collapse(0);          // Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
$WTable2 = $WrdDoc->Tables->Add($tableRange, 2, 2);
```

Comment: First of all Thanks.
Then... I can tell you that your intuition is correct because it's a question of word command and no binded to php...
So... I resolved by WholeStory command and endkey...
Thank still...

Comment: You're welcome @Federick ... FWIW mimicking user actions (key strokes) is usually *not* the optimum way to approach automating Word. Working with `Ranges` is usually preferred.